# How to get value from input when the input has a space in the name?

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

Maybe this is silly. But I have problem with this. I have dropdown list with some values for example:

```
<select name="Name Kombinezony" class=" fixed-width" id="Name Kombinezony">
<option value="Home">Home</option>
</select>
```

I have problem to get the value from this beacuase the input file has a space in name. The worst is that I need to have a space in name. How to resolve this problem ? I get the value by using:

```
Tools::getValue($category)
```

Kind regards ?

Comment: how about replacing the space with an underscore and remove that latter?

Comment: This is a think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrestaShop will concatenate it with an underscore, so, you can get the value like this: `Tools::getValue('Name_Kombinezony')`

PD. Tested in PS 1.7

Comment: No I have 0 (string). The solution for me is remove the spaces.

Comment: Of course that the best solution is remove the space, but curiously I have tested with a space in PS 1.7 and has changed the space for an underscore.